# Null object reference in Firebase result loop

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to receive all challenges in Firestore and loop over result to add it to an ArrayList.

```
db.collection("challenges")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        if (document.exists()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    Error-> Challenge challenge = document.toObject(Challenge.class);
                            Log.d(TAG, challenge.getUid() + " => " + challenge.getText());
                            challengeList.add(document.getData().toString());
                        }
                    }

                    challengeListView.setAdapter(challengeArrayAdapter);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

Error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
```

Line:

```
Challenge challenge = document.toObject(Challenge.class);
```

The log with `Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());`
is working.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

This is my my Challenge Class:

```
public class Challenge {

    private Date createdAt;
    private Date changedAt;
    private String uid;
    private String text;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    public Challenge(String uid, String text, double longitude, double latitude) {
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        this.createdAt = currentDate;
        this.changedAt = currentDate;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.text = text;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude; }

    public Date getCreatedAt() { return createdAt; }

    public Date getChangedAt() { return changedAt; }

    public String getUid() { return uid; }

    public String getText() { return text; }

    public double getLongitude() { return longitude; }

    public double getLatitude() { return latitude;}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change this line of code:

```
Challenge challenge = document.toObject(Challenge.class);
```

with

```
Map<String, Object> map = task.getResult().getData());
```

To use `toObject()` method for a single document, please use the following code:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("challenges").document("yourDocument");
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        Challenge challenge = documentSnapshot.toObject(Challenge.class);
    }
});
```

The error is because of your modell class. Your code looks good. Add the no-argument constructor in your model class. Keep that code or use the `Map<String, Object>` and your problem will be solved.

To add the no-argument constructor, please add the following line of code in your model class:

```
public Challenge() {} //Needed for Firebase
```

after the decalaration of class variables.

Comment: but I want to query all data in challenges. Is there a way to do it without selecting a specific document?

Comment: If you want a single document, you need to use the above code. If you want all documents you need to loop through the entire collection.

Comment: but I thought I do that like the firebase documentation to query all data of a collection

Comment: What does `document.toObject(Challenge.class)` return? Null?

Comment: Please share also your `Challenge` class.

Comment: added challenge class

Comment: I was right. The no-argument constructor is missing. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late but it may help some one in my case my object was

```
public class RFQ {
    public String content,email,receiverKey,productKey,companyKey;
    public Sender sender;
    public Long createAt;

    public RFQ() {
    }

    public RFQ(String content, String email, String receiverKey, String productKey, String companyKey, Sender sender, Long createAt) {
        this.content = content;
        this.email = email;
        this.receiverKey = receiverKey;
        this.productKey = productKey;
        this.companyKey = companyKey;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.createAt = createAt;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Long getCreateAt() {
        return createAt;
    }

    public void setCreateAt(Long createAt) {
        this.createAt = createAt;
    }

    public String getReceiverKey() {
        return receiverKey;
    }

    public void setReceiverKey(String receiverKey) {
        this.receiverKey = receiverKey;
    }

    public String getProductKey() {
        return productKey;
    }

    public void setProductKey(String productKey) {
        this.productKey = productKey;
    }

    public String getCompanyKey() {
        return companyKey;
    }

    public void setCompanyKey(String companyKey) {
        this.companyKey = companyKey;
    }

    public Sender getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(Sender sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }
}
```

Everything is proper here but still, I was getting the error that was due to my Sender class in my Sender class I missed to place non-args constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Bro, you need to add Default Constructor in your Challenge Model class as it is needed for Firebase

> **`public Challenge() {}`** //add this line